# Code Completion In Aptana

Tags: javascript, aptana, code-completion

Is there code completion for custom javascript libraries in Apatana, if yes, how do we activate it?

Answer (score 1):

Some code completion happens automatically (like recognizing function definitions), but in general, the best mechanism is to provide a code completion file. Check here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

Comment: Can you explain how I am supposed to use that? I mean, in the jQuery code assist section, it just says add the `.sdocml` file. Where should I add it?